# jqwidgets jqxGrid go to the page of a specific row

Tags: jqxgrid, jqwidget

My jqxgrid has paging, and assume I call

```
$('#jqxGrid').jqxGrid('selectrow', 20);
```

I want the grid can go to the page with the selected row, but I don't know which page contains the selected row (bound index 20), so how to do it?

need manual calculate which page contains the selected row first?

Comment: but after select the desired row, will the grid also jump to that page? e.g. if that row is in page2, how to go to page2 (the problem is I don't know which page that row in before)

Comment: please post the entire code of your instantiation for $('#jqxGrid') with the column models and all of the properties you set